# How to add Top Level GestureDetector to Flutter?

Tags: timer, flutter, navigationbar, gesturedetector

I have home page and **bottomNavigationBar** with 3 to 5 Page view as shown below. Each page view opens new page (**new ASummary(index: this._page)**,) such as;

- a_summary.dart,
- b_summary.dart etc.

Each child page (ex: a_summary.dart) opens a different **pages** with user interaction using;

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => new Account()));
```

Each Summary pages also opens a different pages with user interaction using Navigator.push. The navigation tree/page (a_summary.dart) is very deep, such as a_summary page as deep as 10 page.

```
 - a_summary stateful
    - aa.page
      - aaa.page
         - aaaa.page
             - aaaaa.page etc.
```

In home page I have a timer set to 5 min. If no user interaction in 5 min the timer jumps to login page. my home page the GestureDetector and timer works if the user has interaction with bottomNavigationBar pages. I use GestureDetector to all my pages. my timer function in home.dart. But when I enter rooted pages like aaaaa.page or any other similar pages my home GestureDetector and timer is not working.

home.dart page code:

```
class _MyUserHomePageState extends State<MyUserHomePage> {
  Timer _timer;
  PageController _pageController;
  int _page;

  // TODO: MAIN BUILD WIDGET
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: _handleUserInteraction,
        child: new Scaffold(
            body: new PageView(
              children: [
                new ASummary(index: this._page),
                new BSummary(index: this._page),
                new CSummary(index: this._page),
                new DSummary(index: this._page),
                new ESummary(index: this._page),
              ],
              onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
              controller: _pageController,
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  canvasColor: capitalDarkGreen,
                  primaryColor: capitalLightGreen,
              child: new BottomNavigationBar(
                items: [
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(title: new Text( “A”,)),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(title: new Text( “B”,)),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(title: new Text( “C”,)),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(title: new Text( “D”,)),
                    new BottomNavigationBarItem(title: new Text( “E”,)),
                ],
                onTap: navigationTapped,
                currentIndex: this._page,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
 }
```

Each rooted page is under different folder. My question is how to add  Top Level GestureDetector to my Flutter app so I can activate/deactivate my home.dart timer using GestureDetector even my app deeply rooted? Or is there better option for this idea?

**The idea** is after user login, if no user interaction 5 min, app automatically jumps to login page.

Comment: It won't be possible with `GestureDetector`. You may want to use `Listener` or a custom `RenderObject`.

Comment: thanks Remi, where I can some example so I can modify my code? How do I use global RenderObject or Listener so I can access deeply rooted page (*.dart)?